# Image resize before upload without preview javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, html5-canvas, image-resizing

I want to avoid uploading big/heavy image files.

I prefer HTML5 FileAPI library for this job.

All other functionality is added (upload, re-order, etc.), so I only need the image-resize function.

**CASE:**

On the page there is an input for multiple files.

On input change event (when adding files), resize the entered images/files and append them to FormData(), then send the FormData() to PHP script via ajax.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
   var formData = resizeImages(this.files[0]);   
   uploadResizedImages(formData);
});

function resizeImages(files){
   formData = new FormData();

   //For each image, resize it and append to formData
   //resize file part missing....
   formData.append('files[]',this);//Appending to formData (this = currently iterated file)

   return formData;//Return the formData with resized images
}
```

Anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience you cannot manipulate the image on the client side then upload the manipulated image in tact via a file input in a form.

The way I have done what you are trying to do in the past involves a few steps.

1. Select image using a file input
2. Read the file as a dataURL
3. Use canvas to manipulate the image as needed
4. Export the new image as a dataUrl
5. Use ajax to upload the image to the server as a dataURL
6. Use server side functions to convert the dataUrl to an image and store

https://jsfiddle.net/0hmhumL1/

```
function resizeInCanvas(img){
  /////////  3-3 manipulate image
    var perferedWidth = 2700;
  var ratio = perferedWidth / img.width;
  var canvas = $("<canvas>")[0];
  canvas.width = img.width * ratio;
  canvas.height = img.height * ratio;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //////////4. export as dataUrl
  return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

When uploading as a dataUrl you increase the size (bandwidth required) of the manipulated image by about 20% so you may not see the savings you are looking for unless you are changing the image size considerably.

Comment: I want the image size max 1920x1080. When I shoot photos with my camera, the resolution is 6000x4000 and the size is from 8Mb to 20 Mb. By resizing it, it would be around ~2 Mb (hopefully). Also, I think I can add jpg quality reduction to get even lower sizes. Btw. will I receive these dataURL's as $_FILES in PHP or as $_POST? 
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What about reverting the DataURL to Blob object, append to FormData and then send?

Comment: Based on your previous question.  iff you change your preferredWidth to 1920 the solution would re size the images correctly.  I am not a php programmer so I do not know the answer, but my guess would be $_POST since it is not longer actually a file and just data being transfered

Comment: I have tried this... however the file size ends up so much higher with canvas...original being 37kb and uploaded version afterwards being 387kb... what gives?

Comment: Thanks, it solved my needs! @Carine, for small files sometimes that happens, but if you use a Mb file, is really shrinks.  I have created an Ember component for this, if anyone needs it, send me a msg.